# Can we store files and attachments in external storage from Salesforce

Tags: apex

Can we store files and attachments in external storage from SFDC. We are storing our file on NAS(network storage). Since size of files is very big , so we store file on NAS and keep the storage link in sfdc.Please let me know how can we achieve this.

Comment: The simplest way to do this with minimal functionality is just to use URL fields in Salesforce on the objects, however this only gives you the pointer to the file without any dynamic update or retrieval of metadata about the file is very limiting. Do you have more specific details of what you need to be able to do with the files or see about them in terms of properties?

Comment: In our company we use [FTP Attachments](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ZwDEAU) by Enzigma. It can store your attachs on local disks, cloud storages, ftp, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not cheap or inexpensive, this *might* be an appropriate situation to consider implementing Lightning Connect which would use ODATA to connect with your NAS database that's external to Salesforce. Lightning Connect now has Read/Write capabilities and integrates very well with Salesforce. You'd get the benefits of the less expensive storage on your NAS yet still have seamless integration with Salesforce that would be transparent to your community users.

I'm in no way suggesting this is the only solution, instead that this is an option you may want to consider.